# how can i adjust the password profile of a user while iam creating it on azure active directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

*while iam creating a new user on AzureAD i can't adjust the password profile of the user after i set
it with a temporary password ex:i wanna make the user change his password when he first signIn rule i wanna change that using the azure portal
*i can do that using microsoft graph api while iam creating the user i can adjust the user password profile so easy but not through the azure ad portal

so here is a picture of the user form and what [image]it is showing me

and here is the object iam using when creating user using Microsoft graph api

```
 { 
"accountEnabled": true,
 "city": "Seattle",
 "country": "United States",
 "department": "Sales & Marketing",
 "displayName": "Melissa Darrow",
 "givenName": "Melissa", 
"jobTitle": "Marketing Director",
 "mailNickname": "MelissaD",

*"passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration",
"passwordProfile": {
    "password": "d4a57301-fddf-a947-5401-168f8637a444",
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
},*


"officeLocation": "131/1105",
"postalCode": "98052",
"preferredLanguage": "en-US",
"state": "WA",
"streetAddress": "9256 Towne Center Dr., Suite 400",
"surname": "Darrow",
"mobilePhone": "+1 206 555 0110",
"usageLocation": "US",
"userPrincipalName": "MelissaD@{domain}"
```

}

here i can adjust the passowrd profile so iam asking how can i do that on the azure AD

thx...

Comment: Hey @Ahmed taha, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

•   When you try to create a user, you are getting an option to **‘Auto-generate password’** or **‘Let me create the password’**, this itself implies that even after your selecting any option of them above while creating a user and further communicating the user of the new password set for his account by selecting any one of the options above, the user will still have to set the password when he signs in to Azure AD for the first time using the password that you(administrator) gave him. That is, ***the password set for the new user’s account by you will be the temporary password and will need to be reset by the user when he signs in for the first time in Azure AD.***

•   Thus, even when you select any option for creating the user’s password, the user will still have to change his password during his first login to Azure AD. Hence, for changing the password profile of the Azure AD, you can configure the fine-grained password policies through the Azure AD Administrative Center by accessing the following link which will redirect you to Azure AD Administrative Center: -

https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Overview

Once, on that link, then configure the ***Fine-grained password policies*** according to those as stated in the link below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/adac/introduction-to-active-directory-administrative-center-enhancements--level-100-#fine_grained_pswd_policy_mgmt

For you to configure the settings mentioned in the above link, you will have need to have **‘Azure AD Domain Services’** managed domain in your subscription and the managed domain must have been created using the **‘Resource Manager deployment model’**. Please go through the above link for more details.